# Squiggly Seekbar with Animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, seekbar, flutter-design

I am trying to implement **Squiggly Seekbar with Animation** in Flutter.

Here is the example how its looks like [[Video Preview]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1umRz2npuAINF7710JNm5TgTdmewkVDqe/view):

[image]

I have tried some of the code as below

```
class MyWaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    debugPrint('Widget: ${size.width}, Height: ${size.height}');
    path.lineTo(0.0, 100.0);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 100.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            size.width - (size.width / 16) - (i * size.width / 8),
            0.0,
            size.width - ((i + 1) * size.width / 8),
            size.height - (size.height * 0.8));
      } else {
        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            size.width - (size.width / 16) - (i * size.width / 8),
            size.height - (size.height * 0.6),
            size.width - ((i + 1) * size.width / 8),
            size.height - (size.height * 0.8));
      }
    }

    path.lineTo(0.0, 40.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I took an help of [this blog](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/47/how-to-create-wave-curves-animation-using-clipper-path-in-flutter-app/), Can anyone help to make it infinite for Animation?

Comment: I think you wanted to use CustomPainter instead of `CustomClipper`

Comment: yes, you need `CustomPainter`, and not `CustomClipper` - see `repaint` parameter in `CustomPainter` constructor if you want your painter to repaint the next frame of your curvy animation

Comment: For Jetpack Compose, see [this repository](https://github.com/mahozad/wavy-slider).

Comment: Related question for Kotlin and Jetpack Compose and Compose Multiplatform: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77927207/8583692

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i just [published](https://pub.dev/packages/squiggly_slider) a package that does exactly what you are looking for!

the github repo is linked there in case you are interested in its inner workings